# Trying to make a stoplight that changes colour depending on sound (loud sound = red, normal sound = green etc)

Tags: python, loops, canvas, tkinter, real-time

I have been trying to make a Tkinter app that works as a feedback stoplight for the sound that is produced. so for example when its getting loud in the library you get a red light, but when its normal then its green and so on.

Basically I have created a Tkinter app with a canvas and made 3 circles in a rectangle (the stoplight) also made a function to get the input from your mic to see how high or low the sound is.

This code is made in a seperate file to get the input sound:

```
def decide_colour():

    def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames,tijd, status):
        global colour
        volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)
        print(volume_norm)
        time.sleep(1)

        #set fill colour
        if volume_norm > 2 and volume_norm <4:
            colour = "yellow"
        elif volume_norm > 4:
            colour = "red"
        else:
            colour = "green"

        print(colour)

    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
        sd.sleep(duration * 1000)


decide_colour()
```

And this is the tkinter app that should display it:

```
class TrafficLights:

    def __init__(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.title("Stoplicht")
        root.configure(bg='black')
        root.geometry('460x400')

        # Frame voor widgets
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.grid()

        self.colour = StringVar()

        # canvas voor lichten
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=460, height=400, bg="black")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(190, 10, 310, 350, outline='white', fill='black')
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.oval_red = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 20, 300, 120, fill="white")

        self.oval_yellow = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 130, 300, 230, fill="white")

        self.oval_green = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 240, 300, 340, fill="white")

        # kleurbepaling voor de cirkels
        def change_color(self):

            if colour == 'red':
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="red")
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="white")
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="white")
            elif colour == 'yellow':
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="white")
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="yellow")
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="white")
            elif colour == 'green':
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="white")
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="white")
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="green")

        change_color(self)

        root.after(500, change_color(self))
        #root.after(500, TrafficLights)

        root.mainloop()


while True:
    decide_colour()
    TrafficLights()
```

But it's stuck in a loop. and also by getting rid of the `while` statement it will just open it once. But I want it to keep running and I want it to change the color of the stoplight. I have been trying for days, looking for answers. but I'm just really stuck right now.

Comment: What is the `sd` being used in `decide_colour()`? One—but not the only—thing that's wrong is the `root.after(500, change_color(self))` call which should be written `root.after(500, change_color, self)`.

Comment: the sd is for the sounddevice, it returns the value of the sounds every second,

Comment: OK, however to provide you with a decent answer I still need to understand what your code is doing better. How does the `with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):` and following `sd.sleep(duration * 1000)` work? This is necessary to allow rewriting (or replacing) `decide_colour()` with something that works.

Comment: i imported sounddevice as sd, so sd.stream(callback=print_sound): prints the input from my mic into the console, the sd.sleep(duration*1000) is for how long it will be running

Comment: Sorry, but that really doesn't describe what I wanted to know. What is the effect of the `callback=` argument, and why is the `sd.sleep(duration * 1000)` inside a `with` statement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the organization of your program. That `while` loop is not needed. I made a simple example of how `after` is suppose to work. The function that gets called in the `after` loop should get the data it needs from the `decide_colour()` function. In this example, it would be `my_count()`.

```
from tkinter import *

class Counter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.count = 0
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self):
        self.count_label         = Label(self)
        self.count_label["text"] = str(self.count)
        self.count_label["pady"] = 5
        self.count_label.grid()


    def my_count(self):
        self.count = self.count+1
        self.count_label["text"] = str(self.count)


root = Tk()
counter = Counter(master=root)

#do you app set up here
root.title("Counter")
root.geometry('460x400')

def do_one_iteration():
    counter.my_count()
    root.after(500, do_one_iteration)
do_one_iteration()

counter.mainloop()
```

Comment: your answer is definitely helpful, though i am not sure how to use this on my code, i found a way, but it's not like yours

Answer (score 0):

okay it is not the answer i wanted but it is an answer nonetheless

i put the codes together and with some tweaking i came to this.

```
from tkinter import *
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import time

duration = 1  #


def decide_colour():
    def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, tijd, status):
        global colour
        volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)
        time.sleep(1)

        # set fill colour
        if 2 < volume_norm < 4:
            colour = "yellow"
        elif volume_norm > 4:
            colour = "red"
        else:
            colour = "green"

        print(volume_norm, colour)

    with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
        sd.sleep(duration * 1000)


class TrafficLights:

    def __init__(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.title("Stoplicht")
        root.configure(bg='black')
        root.geometry('460x400')

        # Frame voor widgets
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.grid()

        self.colour = StringVar()

        # canvas voor lichten
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=460, height=400, bg="black")
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(190, 10, 310, 350, outline='white', fill='black')
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.oval_red = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 20, 300, 120, fill="red")
        self.oval_yellow = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 130, 300, 230, fill="white")
        self.oval_green = self.canvas.create_oval(200, 240, 300, 340, fill="white")

    def create_frame():
        decide_colour()

        if colour == 'red':
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="red")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="white")
        elif colour == 'yellow':
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="yellow")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="white")
        elif colour == 'green':
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_red, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_yellow, fill="white")
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.oval_green, fill="green")

        create_frame()

        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        root.destroy()
        return


while True:
    TrafficLights()
```

So now it opens a new mainloop after one second and destroying the mainloop that came before. I actually wanted it to update in one mainloop but could not figure out how, so if anyone knows please tell me